# Two different Rejection steps in Approval process

Tags: approval-process

In the approval process, there are 2 different business process to reject the process, via "Reject for Correction" and "Reject for Quarantine".

1. When "Reject for Correction" is selected then we have to reset the Approval 
   Status field, unlock the record and also allow user to re-initiate the process 
   again.
2. When "Reject for Quarantine" is selected then we have to retain the lock, 
   send an email and update the status before exiting.

Now my question is how do I enable the user to have two Reject options in the out of box approval process? Because in standard approval process, for Reject, we have just have the standard action and then it exits.
FYI: The standard Final rejection action always either lock or unlocks the record but in my case it depends on the type of rejection.

Any ideas without Apex is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An approval process cannot enforce validation rules https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007lcT..

If you could enforce validation rules then you could have the user populate a custom field called rejection_reason__c and then reject.

Without an apex trigger we have not been able to find a solution to this.. Interested if anyone has any other solutions also!!